# How do I display MACD in table format in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a table in which MACD histogram values do not overlap and are kept separate from one another, similar to the example script I found. How can I achieve this? Each box represents a candle.

Here is an example of the desired table format:

[image: Table Format]